# Problems with starting to use SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am a newbie to asp.net but have been programming with vb.net. I have difficulties in learning how to use SQL Server.

I have been using AccessDB but now I want to use SQL Server. I have read a lot of articles on net but seems confusing to me.

I have installed IIS Express, VS SP1, ASP.net MVC 4, yet when I click Add New Item from my App_Data, I only see SQL Server DB but when I try to add it, it conflicts with 2008 and 2008 RS, after telling it to continue, it says it cant connect to `localDB`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: please put your error in the question.

Comment: Thanks for reply - First it shows Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2) compatibility issues then after a little delay it says connection timed out.

Comment: Problems solved. My connection string in web.config was the problem. I was not using the correct app name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, created the mdf file and attached it to my ASP website using Add New Data Source following the dialog. Change the web.config file to look at my web server directory. That is after creating a login for it on the web control panel.

My web.config file, under Configuration looks like this after uploading and setting up the mdf,

```
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="DBNAME" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=false;User ID=User;Password=Pass" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```